# Docker-compose filebeat connection issue to logstash

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, filebeat

I am running logstash and filebeat inside separate docker-compose.yml. But filebeat cannot connect to logstash. I can properly telnet into logstash `telnet 127.0.0.1 5044` after I wait for the logstash pipelines to start.

Filebeat cannot create a connection. I get this error.
`ERROR  pipeline/output.go:74   Failed to connect: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5044: getsockopt: connection refused`

This is my docker-compose for filebeat.

```
version: '2'

services:
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.2.3
    container_name: filebeat
    user: root
    volumes:
      - flask-sync:/home/flask/app/web:ro
      - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro

volumes:
  flask-sync:
    external: true
```

This is my filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/flask/app/web/tmp/log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]
```

This is my docker-compose for logstash

```
version: '2'

services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.2.4
    container_name: logstash
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/logstash.conf:ro
      - ./logstash/config/:/usr/share/logstash/config/:ro
    command: bin/logstash -f logstash.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

This is my logstash.conf

```
input { 
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
}


output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: The filebeat's configuration of `127.0.0.1:5044` would refer to the localhost of the filebeat container. Logstash would not be listening to a port inside of the filebeat container.

So what you want is to have them in the same docker network so that they can talk to each other.

Comment: That solution was really helpful and it worked. Would this docker network work across different AWS instances?

Comment: this is a solution what you find. [elk-with-filebeat-by-docker-compose](https://github.com/gnokoheat/elk-with-filebeat-by-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems:
 Check export the 5044 port in docker-compose.yml

```
    build:
      context: logstash/
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
      - /datos/sna/log:/datos/sna/log
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5044:5044"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```